# obfuscate javascript code without quotes

Tags: javascript

I would like to obfuscate my quote but my obfuscated code always gets with quotes, i need it without quotes does anyone have an idea of how to deal with quotes or a good webpage where i can obfuscate.

```
var _0xf0ee=["\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x69\x6E\x63\x6F\x6C\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x2D\x71\x61\x2E\x74\x69\x65\x72\x63\x6F\x6E\x6E\x65\x63\x74\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D\x2F\x73\x69\x74\x65\x73\x2F\x61\x6C\x6C\x2F\x74\x68\x65\x6D\x65\x73\x2F\x63\x6D\x73\x5F\x70\x75\x62\x6C\x69\x73\x68\x65\x72\x5F\x6C\x69\x67\x68\x74","\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x69\x6E\x63\x6F\x6C\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x2D\x71\x61\x2E\x74\x69\x65\x72\x63\x6F\x6E\x6E\x65\x63\x74\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D","\x69\x6D\x67","\x67\x65\x74\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x73\x42\x79\x54\x61\x67\x4E\x61\x6D\x65","\x6C\x65\x6E\x67\x74\x68","\x76\x61\x6C\x69\x64\x61\x74\x65\x5F\x69\x6D\x61\x67\x65","\x73\x72\x63","\x70\x75\x73\x68","\x63\x6C\x65\x61\x6E\x5F\x75\x6E\x64\x65\x66\x69\x6E\x65\x64","\x66\x69\x6E\x64\x5F\x69\x6D\x61\x67\x65\x73","\x67\x65\x74\x49\x6D\x61\x67\x65\x73\x52\x65\x6E\x64\x65\x72\x65\x64","","\x68\x74\x74\x70","\x69\x6E\x64\x65\x78\x4F\x66","\x67\x65\x74\x4F\x72\x69\x67\x69\x6E\x61\x6C\x57\x69\x64\x74\x68\x4F\x66\x49\x6D\x67","\x67\x65\x74\x41\x74\x74\x72\x69\x62\x75\x74\x65","\x77\x69\x64\x74\x68","\x3C\x64\x69\x76\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x22\x63\x6F\x6C\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x65\x64\x2D\x69\x6D\x61\x67\x65\x73\x2D\x63\x6F\x6E\x74\x61\x69\x6E\x65\x72\x22\x3E","\x3C\x64\x69\x76\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x22\x6F\x76\x65\x72\x6C\x61\x79\x2D\x68\x65\x61\x64\x65\x72\x22\x3E","\x3C\x64\x69\x76\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x22\x69\x6E\x63\x6F\x6C\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x2D\x6C\x6F\x67\x6F\x22\x3E","\x3C\x61\x20\x68\x72\x65\x66\x3D\x22\x23\x22\x3E\x3C\x69\x6D\x67\x20\x73\x72\x63\x3D\x22","\x62\x61\x73\x65\x5F\x75\x72\x6C\x5F\x74\x68\x65\x6D\x65","\x2F\x69\x6D\x61\x67\x65\x73\x2F\x6C\x6F\x67\x6F\x49\x6E\x43\x6F\x6C\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x2E\x70\x6E\x67\x22\x3E\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E","\x3C\x2F\x64\x69\x76\x3E","\x3C\x64\x69\x76\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x22\x61\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x2D\x6C\x69\x6E\x6B\x73\x2D\x67\x72\x6F\x75\x70\x20\x66\x6C\x6F\x61\x74\x2D\x72\x22\x3E","\x3C\x64\x69\x76\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x22\x61\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x2D\x6C\x69\x6E\x6B\x2D\x69\x74\x65\x6D\x22\x3E","\x3C\x62\x75\x74\x74\x6F\x6E\x20\x20\x6F\x6E\x43\x6C\x69\x63\x6B\x3D\x22\x77\x69\x6E\x64\x6F\x77\x2E\x63\x6C\x6F\x73\x65\x28\x29\x22\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x22\x6C\x69\x6E\x6B\x2D\x62\x74\x6E\x20\x75\x69\x2D\x62\x75\x74\x74\x6F\x6E\x2D\x70\x72\x69\x6D\x61\x72\x79\x22\x3E\x43\x6C\x6F\x73\x65\x3C\x2F\x62\x75\x74\x74\x6F\x6E\x3E","\x67\x65\x74\x4C\x69\x73\x74\x49\x6D\x61\x67\x65\x49\x74\x65\x6D\x73","\x3C\x75\x6C\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x22\x63\x6F\x6C\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x65\x64\x2D\x69\x6D\x67\x2D\x6C\x69\x73\x74\x22\x3E","\x67\x65\x74\x49\x6D\x61\x67\x65\x49\x74\x65\x6D","\x62\x61\x73\x65\x5F\x75\x72\x6C","\x3F\x71\x3D\x61\x64\x64\x5F\x69\x6D\x61\x67\x65\x5F\x63\x6F\x6C\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x2F","\x2F\x26\x69\x6D\x61\x67\x65\x53\x6F\x75\x72\x63\x65\x55\x72\x69\x3D","\x55\x52\x4C","\x3C\x6C\x69\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x22\x63\x6F\x6C\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x65\x64\x2D\x69\x6D\x67\x2D\x69\x74\x65\x6D\x22\x3E","\x3C\x61\x20\x6F\x6E\x63\x6C\x69\x63\x6B\x3D\x22\x6A\x61\x76\x61\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74\x3A\x77\x69\x6E\x64\x6F\x77\x2E\x72\x65\x73\x69\x7A\x65\x54\x6F\x28\x35\x30\x30\x2C\x38\x30\x30\x29\x22\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x22\x63\x6F\x6C\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x65\x64\x2D\x69\x6D\x67\x2D\x6C\x69\x6E\x6B\x22\x20\x68\x72\x65\x66\x3D\x22","\x22\x3E","\x3C\x73\x70\x61\x6E\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x22\x63\x6F\x6C\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x65\x64\x2D\x69\x6D\x67\x2D\x77\x72\x61\x70\x70\x65\x72\x22\x3E","\x3C\x69\x6D\x67\x20\x73\x74\x79\x6C\x65\x3D\x22\x6D\x61\x78\x2D\x68\x65\x69\x67\x68\x74\x3A\x20\x31\x38\x30\x70\x78\x3B\x22\x20\x73\x72\x63\x3D\x22","\x3C\x2F\x73\x70\x61\x6E\x3E","\x3C\x64\x69\x76\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x22\x63\x6F\x6C\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x2D\x62\x74\x6E\x22\x3E\x3C\x62\x75\x74\x74\x6F\x6E\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x22\x6C\x69\x6E\x6B\x2D\x62\x74\x6E\x20\x75\x69\x2D\x62\x75\x74\x74\x6F\x6E\x2D\x70\x72\x69\x6D\x61\x72\x79\x22\x3E\x43\x6F\x6C\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x20\x69\x78\x78\x78\x78\x74\x3C\x2F\x62\x75\x74\x74\x6F\x6E\x3E\x3C\x2F\x64\x69\x76\x3E","\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E","\x3C\x2F\x6C\x69\x3E","\x63\x6F\x6E\x73\x6F\x6C\x65\x52\x65\x66","\x6D\x79\x63\x6F\x6E\x73\x6F\x6C\x65","\x77\x69\x64\x74\x68\x3D\x31\x38\x30\x30\x2C\x68\x65\x69\x67\x68\x74\x3D\x38\x30\x30","\x2C\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x62\x61\x72\x3D\x30","\x2C\x74\x6F\x6F\x6C\x62\x61\x72\x3D\x30","\x2C\x73\x74\x61\x74\x75\x73\x3D\x30","\x2C\x73\x63\x72\x6F\x6C\x6C\x62\x61\x72\x73\x3D\x31","\x2C\x72\x65\x73\x69\x7A\x61\x62\x6C\x65\x3D\x31","\x6F\x70\x65\x6E","\x3C\x68\x74\x6D\x6C\x3E","\x3C\x68\x65\x61\x64\x3E","\x3C\x74\x69\x74\x6C\x65\x3E\x43\x6F\x6C\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x20\x69\x74\x21\x3C\x2F\x74\x69\x74\x6C\x65\x3E","\x3C\x6C\x69\x6E\x6B\x20\x72\x65\x6C\x3D\x22\x73\x74\x79\x6C\x65\x73\x68\x65\x65\x74\x22\x20\x68\x72\x65\x66\x3D\x22","\x2F\x63\x73\x73\x2F\x6D\x61\x69\x6E\x2E\x63\x73\x73\x22\x20\x6D\x65\x64\x69\x61\x3D\x22\x73\x63\x72\x65\x65\x6E\x2C\x20\x70\x72\x6F\x6A\x65\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x22\x3E","\x3C\x2F\x68\x65\x61\x64\x3E","\x3C\x62\x6F\x64\x79\x3E","\x3C\x2F\x62\x6F\x64\x79\x3E\x3C\x2F\x68\x74\x6D\x6C\x3E","\x77\x72\x69\x74\x65\x6C\x6E","\x64\x6F\x63\x75\x6D\x65\x6E\x74","\x63\x6C\x6F\x73\x65","\x67\x65\x74\x43\x61\x70\x74\x75\x72\x65\x64\x49\x6D\x61\x67\x65\x73"];(function (){var _0x9f63x1={base_url_theme:_0xf0ee[0],base_url:_0xf0ee[1]};var _0x9f63x2={find_images:function (){var _0x9f63x3=document[_0xf0ee[3]](_0xf0ee[2]);var _0x9f63x4=[];for(var _0x9f63x5=0;_0x9f63x5<_0x9f63x3[_0xf0ee[4]];_0x9f63x5++){if(this[_0xf0ee[5]](_0x9f63x3[_0x9f63x5])){_0x9f63x4[_0xf0ee[7]](_0x9f63x3[_0x9f63x5][_0xf0ee[6]]);} ;} ;return this[_0xf0ee[8]](_0x9f63x4);} ,getCapturedImages:function (){return _0x9f63xd[_0xf0ee[10]](this[_0xf0ee[9]]());} ,validate_image:function (_0x9f63x6){var _0x9f63x7=true;if(_0x9f63x6[_0xf0ee[6]]==_0xf0ee[11]){_0x9f63x7=false;} ;if((_0x9f63x6[_0xf0ee[6]])[_0xf0ee[13]](_0xf0ee[12])<0){_0x9f63x7=false;} ;if(this[_0xf0ee[14]](_0x9f63x6)<200){_0x9f63x7=false;} ;return _0x9f63x7;} ,getOriginalWidthOfImg:function (_0x9f63x8){var _0x9f63x9= new Image();_0x9f63x9[_0xf0ee[6]]=(_0x9f63x8[_0xf0ee[15]]?_0x9f63x8[_0xf0ee[15]](_0xf0ee[6]):false)||_0x9f63x8[_0xf0ee[6]];return _0x9f63x9[_0xf0ee[16]];} ,clean_undefined:function (_0x9f63xa){var _0x9f63xb=[];for(var _0x9f63xc in _0x9f63xa){if(_0x9f63xa[_0x9f63xc]){_0x9f63xb[_0xf0ee[7]](_0x9f63xa[_0x9f63xc]);} ;} ;return _0x9f63xb;} };var _0x9f63xd={getImagesRendered:function (_0x9f63xe){var _0x9f63xf=_0xf0ee[11];_0x9f63xf+=_0xf0ee[17];_0x9f63xf+=_0xf0ee[18];_0x9f63xf+=_0xf0ee[19];_0x9f63xf+=_0xf0ee[20]+_0x9f63x1[_0xf0ee[21]]+_0xf0ee[22];_0x9f63xf+=_0xf0ee[23];_0x9f63xf+=_0xf0ee[24];_0x9f63xf+=_0xf0ee[25];_0x9f63xf+=_0xf0ee[26];_0x9f63xf+=_0xf0ee[23];_0x9f63xf+=_0xf0ee[23];_0x9f63xf+=_0xf0ee[23];_0x9f63xf+=this[_0xf0ee[27]](_0x9f63xe);_0x9f63xf+=_0xf0ee[23];return _0x9f63xf;} ,getListImageItems:function (_0x9f63xe){var _0x9f63xf=_0xf0ee[11];_0x9f63xf+=_0xf0ee[28];for(var _0x9f63x5=0;_0x9f63x5<_0x9f63xe[_0xf0ee[4]];_0x9f63x5++){_0x9f63xf+=this[_0xf0ee[29]](_0x9f63xe[_0x9f63x5]);} ;_0x9f63xf+=_0xf0ee[23];return _0x9f63xf;} ,getImageItem:function (_0x9f63x10){var _0x9f63x11=_0x9f63x1[_0xf0ee[30]]+_0xf0ee[31]+_0x9f63x10+_0xf0ee[32]+document[_0xf0ee[33]];var _0x9f63xf=_0xf0ee[11];_0x9f63xf+=_0xf0ee[34];_0x9f63xf+=_0xf0ee[35]+_0x9f63x11+_0xf0ee[36];_0x9f63xf+=_0xf0ee[37];_0x9f63xf+=_0xf0ee[38]+_0x9f63x10+_0xf0ee[36];_0x9f63xf+=_0xf0ee[39];_0x9f63xf+=_0xf0ee[40];_0x9f63xf+=_0xf0ee[41];_0x9f63xf+=_0xf0ee[42];return _0x9f63xf;} };function _0x9f63x12(_0x9f63x13){top[_0xf0ee[43]]=window[_0xf0ee[51]](_0xf0ee[11],_0xf0ee[44],_0xf0ee[45]+_0xf0ee[46]+_0xf0ee[47]+_0xf0ee[48]+_0xf0ee[49]+_0xf0ee[50]);top[_0xf0ee[43]][_0xf0ee[61]][_0xf0ee[60]](_0xf0ee[52]+_0xf0ee[53]+_0xf0ee[54]+_0xf0ee[55]+_0x9f63x1[_0xf0ee[21]]+_0xf0ee[56]+_0xf0ee[57]+_0xf0ee[58]+_0x9f63x13+_0xf0ee[59]);top[_0xf0ee[43]][_0xf0ee[61]][_0xf0ee[62]]();} ;_0x9f63x12(_0x9f63x2[_0xf0ee[63]]());} )();
```

Comment: `/foo/.source` or `String.fromCharCode(102,111,111)`